# TD not aligned correctly

Tags: html-table

Im having a little trouble trying to align this table, also the padding is not working. Im trying to make the textbox start in the same position as the checkbox but below it, also im trying to add padding to the first tr by doing it to the td but its not working.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" Style="margin-left: 165px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
  </td>
  <td>
    <label Style="padding-bottom: 50px;">Label for Checkbox</label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <label Width="163px">#Another Label:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="textbox" MaxLength="20" Width="163px">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/u5vu5mn6/

Comment: Check box is on the right because style says `margin-left: 165px;`. It's a lot of margin.

Comment: Yes, and thats fine for me. The problem is that the textbox isn't aligned under the checkbox.

Comment: move checkbox to second td and add `margin-left:0`

Comment: Nice, its align perfectly. Tho the padding problem still persist.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Added style="padding-bottom: 5px;" to the td which has got the checkbox and label.